# What does auto-scaling in wso2 elb mean?

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb

Can WSO2 ELB automatically start another instance of ESB when the limit is reached?
If yes can I get a miniature example with a limit as 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. WSO2 ELB can automatically spawn instances using the configured cartridges.

However, WSO2 ELB is no longer recommended and it has been discontinued. We recommend [WSO2 Private PaaS](http://wso2.com/cloud/private-paas/) if you need an auto-scaling platform with WSO2 products. With WSO2 Private PaaS, you can use [auto-scaling policies](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Working+with+Auto-scaling+Policies).