# ELB with auto scaling

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want a suggestion for ELB with **auto scaling** (automatically start a new instance when the load is more) for WSO2 ESB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please use "[WSO2 Private PaaS](http://wso2.com/cloud/private-paas/)". You can have ["auto scaling" WSO2 ESB instances](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Features) with the WSO2 Private PaaS.

As I mentioned in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31177358/1955702), Auto scaling with a load balancer was not very successful and that's why WSO2 ELB is no longer recommended for auto scaling.

It's not mandatory to use [WSO2 Private PaaS](http://wso2.com/cloud/private-paas/) to auto scale WSO2 products. You can use your preferred IaaS features for auto scaling.

For example, you can use [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/). You can create your own AMIs with WSO2 Products and use some configuration management solution like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet) to configure products when a new instance is spawned. [WSO2 Private PaaS also uses Puppet to configure WSO2 cartridge instances](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Creating+a+New+Cartridge).

In EC2, you can dynamically scale using various metrics. For more info, see 
[Auto Scaling Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/). When you use EC2, you can use the [Amazon ELB](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

With WSO2 Private PaaS, WSO2 Cartridges are readily available. (With puppet configurations etc and those cartridges can auto scale according to configured [policies](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Smart+Policies))

Answer (score 0):

The WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer has been discontinued. You can download NGinx Plus - the load balancer by [NGinx](http://nginx.com/products/) - for which we provide support.

If your are currently using WSO2 ELB and need guidance, please visit our documentation [page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ELB211/WSO2+Elastic+Load+Balancer+Documentation), Spacially [Auto-Scaling in Load Balancer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ELB211/Auto-Scaling+in+Load+Balancer)